# What gender do the Z-series computers by Konrad Zuse have?

Tags: gender

What gender do the Z-series computers (Z3...) by Konrad Zuse have?
Der, die oder das?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On [this site](http://www5.in.tum.de/lehre/seminare/math_nszeit/SS03/vortraege/zuse/pages/Zuse_Z3_Radio.htm) there's a quote by Zuse himself:

> "Das Gerät wurde zum größten Teil aus Altmaterial gebaut; die [...] Wicklungen der Relais waren deshalb uneinheitlich. Ich musste verschiedene Spannungen benutzen, um die Relais einigermaßen gut zusammenschalten zu können, was viel überflüssige Arbeit verursachte. Dennoch war die Z3 verhältnismäßig betriebssicher. Leider konnte sie nur von mir gewartet werden."

So Zuse himself used "die".

Answer (score 1):

We say "eine Zuse", "die Z3" (or any other number) or "die Zuse Z3". So, in every imaginable combination the Zuses are female.

See, for example, the German Wikipedia articles:

- http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zuse_Z2
- http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zuse_Z3
- and so on

Answer (score 0):

Wikipedia verwendet die weibliche Form, weil es Rechenmaschinen waren; siehe https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zuse_Z1

Comment: Ich dachte es währe vielleicht männlich, da wir es so in einen Lehrbuch hatten und der Zuse ja auch männlich war.

Comment: Hätte auch sein können -- der Rechner. Wahrscheinlich war damals "die Rechenmaschine" geläufiger und das Wort wurde erst später zu "Rechner" gekürzt (und damit männlich)

Comment: (Offtopic, @DavidKnaack `*währe` wird ohne *h* geschrieben.)

Comment: @ComFreek: "währe" (ohne Stern, da existent) wird selbstverständlich mit "h" geschrieben (auf dass die Erkenntnis ewig währe). Nur, dass hier nicht der Konjunktiv I von "währen" gemeint war, sondern der Konjunktiv II von "sein", der in der Tat ohne "h" geschrieben wird.

Comment: @celtschk Das war mir beim Schreiben des Kommentars durchaus bewusst, nur wollte ich den OP als Einsteiger in die deutsche Sprache nicht weiter verwirren ;) Dennoch ein berechtigter Hinweis!

Answer (score 0):

It’s  *die Zuse-Z2-Rechenmaschine* oder *der Zuse-Z2-Rechner.*

Comment: Can you back this up in any way?

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: Rechner und Maschine dürften wirklich unsstrittig sein - schlag es sonst im Duden nach.

Comment: @userunknown: Es geht mir nicht um das Geschlecht von *Rechner* und *Maschine,* sondern darum, dass sich das auch auf *Z3* usw. überträgt. Es sagt ja auch niemand *die Mercedes,* obwohl es *die Mercedes-Limousine* gibt (um mir ein Beispiel aus den Fingern zu saugen).

Comment: When Bikini was loaned, the closest existing word was *der Badeanzug*. Therefore it is likely that its gender was either directly adopted or is a remnant of the composite *Bikini-Badeanzug*, which might have been used when the word was new and not well-known. Same here.

Comment: *Unstrittig*, ansonsten tatsächlich *uns strittig*.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: Mercedes ist ein Wort das jeder kennt und jeder nutzt. Daher hat sich der diesbezügliche, verfestigte Sprachgebrauch rumgesprochen. Vom Z3 reden so wenige, dass sich da noch kein Sprachgebrauch durchgesetzt hat, so dass die Sprache an der Stelle knetbar geblieben ist. Es heißt ja auch der T40 (der Laptop, das Notebook, das Thinkpad, der Rechner, der Computer, die 40).

Comment: Das ist ja alles schön und gut, aber eben deutlich mehr, als in der Antwort steht.